# Compute shader uniform optimized away improperly?

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

Getting the location of the uniform 'uniform Sphere spheres[10]' (via glGetUniformLocation(program, name)). Return -1 even though there are other uniforms in the program (frustum_planes) that work.

The frustum_planes and the spheres uniforms are also used at the same places which makes it weird that only one of the two are present.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

**Shader**

```
#version 460 core
// Required by compute shaders apparently
// Process one object per shader invocation (optimisation?)
layout (local_size_x = 1) in;

struct Sphere {
    vec3 center;
    float radius;
};

uniform Sphere spheres[10];

// Plane defined as: Ax + By + Cz = D
uniform vec4 frustum_planes[6];

uint test(Sphere obj, vec4 plane) {
    const float distance = plane.x * obj.center.x + plane.y * obj.center.y + plane.z * obj.center.z + plane.w;
    if (distance < -obj.radius) {
        return 0; // Negative halfspace
    }
    return 1; // Positive halfspace or on the plane
}

/// Same as the OpenGL provided struct: DrawElementsIndirectCommand
struct DrawCommand {
    uint count; // Num elements (vertices)
    uint instanceCount; // Number of instances to draw (a.k.a primcount)
    uint firstIndex; // Specifies a byte offset (cast to a pointer type) into the buffer bound to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER to start reading indices from.
    uint baseVertex; // Specifies a constant that should be added to each element of indices​ when chosing elements from the enabled vertex arrays.
    uint baseInstance; // Specifies the base instance for use in fetching instanced vertex attributes.
    // 20 bytes
    uint padding0;
    uint padding1;
    uint padding2;
    // 32 bytes (multiple of 16)
};

// One draw command per object 
// Command buffer backed by Shader Storage Object Buffer (SSBO)
layout(std140, binding = 0) writeonly buffer DrawCommandsBlock {
    DrawCommand draw_commands[];
};

void main() {
    const uint idx = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;

    uint inside = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        inside += test(spheres[idx], frustum_planes[i]) << i;
    }

    const uint INSIDE_ALL_PLANES = 63; // = 0b111111;
    const bool visible = inside == INSIDE_ALL_PLANES;
    draw_commands[idx].count = 25350; // sphere.indices.size();
    draw_commands[idx].instanceCount = visible ? 1 : 0; // This is the trick right here
    draw_commands[idx].baseInstance = 0;
    draw_commands[idx].baseVertex = 0;
    draw_commands[idx].padding0 = 0; // Avoid optimisation 
    draw_commands[idx].padding1 = 0;
    draw_commands[idx].padding2 = 0;
}
```

**Working glGetUniformLocation call**

```
glGetUniformLocation(gl_state.cull_shader.gl_program, "spheres[0].center");
```

**main.cpp**

```
  glUseProgram(gl_state.cull_shader.gl_program);
  if (glGetUniformLocation(gl_state.cull_shader.gl_program, "frustum_planes") == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Work!" << std::endl;
  }
  if (glGetUniformLocation(gl_state.cull_shader.gl_program, "spheres") == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Does not work?!" << std::endl;
  }
  glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_state.cull_shader.gl_program, "spheres"), NUM_OBJECTS, &bounding_volumes[0].pos.x);
  glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_state.cull_shader.gl_program, "frustum_planes"), 6, glm::value_ptr(frustum[0]));
  glDispatchCompute(NUM_OBJECTS, 1, 1);
  glMemoryBarrier(GL_COMMAND_BARRIER_BIT | GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT); // Buffer objects affected by this bit are derived from the GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER binding.
```

Comment: Well that might be A problem but is not THE problem here. I think I messed up when copying otherwise this should compile fine.. I cast Murder on your Nicol Bolas. Put him in the graveyard.

Comment: Aha! That's very good to know! Said and done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to query locations of uniforms that are not basic types or arrays of basic types. The [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection#Naming) states:

> The introspection APIs will often make a single "variable" definition in GLSL appear as though it were multiple variables. This is done for variables that are not basic types or arrays of basic types (note that in GLSL, "basic types" include vector and matrix types).
>
> ...
>
> Instead, each sub-element of the struct that is a basic type is visible.

This means, you can't query `spheres` (or `spheres[0]`). What you have to do is to query each member of each struct separately. In order to get the location of the first Sphere's center, you'll have to query for `spheres[0].center`.

Note, that querying `frustum_planes` works as expected because it is a array of vec4 (which is a basic type).

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. glGetUniformLocation does nothing when passed -1 as the location (great design, truely).